# How openssl hashed output of private key form should not display filepath name

Tags: unix, openssl

I have used below commands to get hashed form of my private key.

```
> openssl dgst -sha256 test.pem
out put : **SHA256(test.pem)= 56403847478784787684fe5674d1df**
```

How do I get key output alone with out filename ex: "56403847478784787684fe5674d1df" alone.

Comment: If you supply the file as a stdin redirect instead of an argument `openssl dgst -sha256 <test.pem` it displays `(stdin)= <hash in hex>` which does not include the filename but does include more than just the hash value. (Note it does not include the name of the hash.) If you use `-binary` with _either_ argument or stdin it outputs _only_ the hash value in binary: no filename or 'stdin', no hashname, no parens or equalsign or space, no newline -- but whether you can use binary is a different question, for one thing you can't cut&paste it.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think you can do it by using directly an openssl parameter.**

However you can do it by using `pipe` with the `cut` command. 
Example :

```sh
$ openssl dgst -sha256 test.pem | cut -d " " -f 2
56403847478784787684fe5674d1df
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Apr-2023 using:

```
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

then redirecting the file to stdin will suppress the emission of the filename and other formatting noise and will yield only the hash:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 < test.pem
56403847478784787684fe5674d1df

$ cat test.pem | openssl dgst -sha256
56403847478784787684fe5674d1df
```